# How to add a string of asterisks in Cobol?

Tags: cobol

Problem:

> If the inventory total is less than 50, add a string of two asterisks (**) at the end of the written row to notify the inventory manager that more inventory is needed.  If the inventory total is less than 10, add a string of five asterisks (*****) at the end of the row to let the inventory manager know the need for more inventory is urgent.

How would I make a string of asterisks in Cobol?

Comment: In the first instance, I would look at the Cobol manual. I would guess you either need a loop, or a function that does its own looping. Could you give that a try?

Comment: by making a picture clause that has a value of "*"

Comment: This question should be reopened. The requested answer "How would I make a string of asterisks in Cobol?" is so narrow there are only two possible answers; one, of which, was given before the question was put 'on hold". It simply is not possible to narrow that question further. The first paragraph is merely a explanation for asking the final question. If the first paragraph was the reason for the finding of "too broad", then remove that paragraph.

Comment: This is an excellent question because the answer allows for the creating of a string of any single character. +1

Answer (score 4):

> How would I make a string of asterisks in Cobol?

There are two methods.

The first controls the number of characters at the destination and works best when the data item is initialized before the move. The second controls the number of characters at the source and works best when initialization of the destination is of no concern or when used as part of a `STRING` statement.

### Method 1:

```
move all "*" to data-name-1 (1:number-of-asterisks)
```

For example:

```
   program-id. aster.
   data division.
   working-storage section.
   1 n pic 99.
   1 asterisk-line pic x(10) value space.
   procedure division.
   begin.
       perform varying n from 10 by -1 until n < 1
           move all "*" to asterisk-line (1:n)
           display asterisk-line
           move space to asterisk-line
       end-perform
       stop run
       .
```

Output:

```
**********
*********
********
*******
******
*****
****
***
**
*
```

Notice that the program moves spaces to clear the destination after displaying the asterisks. This is prevent too many asterisks from showing on the following lines.

### Method 2:

```
move asterisks (1:number-of-asterisks) to data-name-1
```

For example:

```
   program-id. aster2.
   data division.
   working-storage section.
   1 n pic 99.
   1 asterisks pic x(10) value all "*".
   1 asterisk-line pic x(10) value space.
   procedure division.
   begin.
       perform varying n from 10 by -1 until n < 1
           move asterisks (1:n) to asterisk-line
           display asterisk-line
       end-perform
       stop run
       .
```

The output is the same as above.

Notice there is no need to `move spaces` (or initialize) the destination before moving the asterisks.